# Find and fill information in Word from Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Currently I am working on a reference-file, where i want to fill in all the personnel in the company. Everybody gets a position and a label. In a lot of different word documents I need to type the names of the people in these roles. The names change a lot and I do not want to change the names in the documents manually all the time. In short: I am looking for a way to make a reference in a word document, when i typ "dev1" it automatically finds the person's name (in this case John) in a reference Excel.[enter image description here][1]

What the table looks like [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR89U.png

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the mail merge feature.

Select the excel file you need to link to, select the corresponding workbook, insert the field, and finally get all the contents.

If you're not familiar with this feature, you can choose step by step mail merge wizard.

[image]